# Обработака данных на хостинге не браузером

Tags: php

Приветствую всех

Собственно хочу запустить PHP код, который обрабатывает данные в бд. Есть ли софт такой (кроме браузера), который может это сделать, ну как на подобии крон при импорте бд в фоновом режиме

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
php5 /path/to/your/code
```

Comment: гениально! спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые хостинги позволяют настроить задание для CRON. Таким образом можно запустить произвольный php скрипт который и сделает необходимую работу. Поинтересуйтесь в службе поддержки хостинга. Если данный хостинг не поддерживает такую функцию - смените хостинг.

вариант с запуском скрипта через браузер возможен, но в этом случае как правило действует ограничение на максимальное время выполнения скрипта. так что скрипт может просто не доработать и испортить данные в базе. на крон такси такого ограничения нет, или же времени для работы CRON таска выделается СУЩЕСТВЕННО больше (нпр. для скрипта 30 сек, для CRON таска 1 час). поэтому очень рекомендую поинтересоваться назначение CRON тасков у службы поддержки хостинга.

Comment: @ivan_pizhenko, я не люблю давать советы тем, что советует мне ( некоторые воспринимают неадекватно ) , но время скрипта можно увеличить до любого значения командой. можно установить бесконечноена счет хостинга - так и сделал. воспользовался тем, где есть поддержка крона, и следующую тему уже на основании этого создам. спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В случае запуска скрипта по крону, обычно нужна команда `/usr/bin/php -q /абсолютный/путь/к/вашему/скрипту/script.php` Но путь к php может быть различным, в зависимости от некоторых параметров.

Как вариант, можно запускать wget-ом, то есть `wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.domain.com/path/script.php`ключик "-O -" задаёт вывод в консоль (вместо сохранения в файл), "-q" делает это "тихо" (без вывода на экран), а "-t 1" указывает делать лишь одну попытку соединения. Проще говоря, вместо скачивания получаем именно однакратный "вызов скрипта" по заданному адресу.

Comment: спасибо, уже часть по использованию крона мне понятна